# Only variables can be passed by reference

Tags: php

```
$explode2 = @end(explode('.', $fetched_delete_data['image']));
$explode3 = @explode('.', $fetched_delete_data['image']);
```

Есть вот такой код, при анализе кода IDE'шкой, выходит ошибка "Only variables can be passed by reference", связанная с этим кодом. Вопрос, как исправить данную ошибку?, и если я её исправлю, то другой код возможно связанный с этим местом, не сломается ли? 
P.S - Версия в IDE - PHP 5.6/7.4, соответственно фикс должен быть совместим с этими версиями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`end` принимает к себе на вход только переменную, т.к. работает с ней по ссылке. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.end.php

> Список параметров ¶
>
> array
>
> Массив. Этот массив передаётся по ссылке, потому что он модифицируется данной функцией. Это означает что вы должны передать его как реальную переменную, а **не как функцию, возвращающую массив, так как по ссылке можно передавать только фактические переменные.**

Нужно результат `explode` положить в отдельную переменную и уже еë передавать в `end`

Comment: то-есть данный код изначально был мёртво-рождённым? Или в какой то олдовой версий PHP он всё-таки работал?
P.S - спасибо!

Comment: Так, как в вопросе, он никогда не работал

Comment: спасибо за решение!